# Нужно ли тире перед названием вина?

Tags: тире

Сегодня я расскажу вам о вине, которое представлено у нас на полке, - «Вальсеррано Резерва», урожай 2016 г.

Answer (score 1):

Обязательно нужна!

***8.**      Вместо запятой при обособлении приложений употребляется тире:
а)      если перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова «а именно», например: Утвержден новый государственный флаг Российской Федерации – трехцветное полотнище с белой, синей и красной продольными полосами...*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91

Comment: Может, "нужн**о**"?

Comment: «Может, "нужно"?» — может))